# alexa-sdk response.listen(reprompt speech)

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, aws-sdk-nodejs

In the [Alexa High Low Game Skill](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-highlowgame), there is the following code in startGameHandlers:

```
'AMAZON.YesIntent': function() {
    this.attributes["guessNumber"] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    this.handler.state = states.GUESSMODE;
    this.response.speak('Great! ' + 'Try saying a number to start the game.').listen('Try saying a number.');
    this.emit(':responseReady');
},
```

After I start the game and response with "yes", I hear the speech output from Alexa "Great! Try saying a number to start the game.". If I do not response, should I expect the reprompt speech of "Try saying a number." being played out by Alexa? What I observed is that the reprompt speech is never played out.

And how long will Alexa wait for my response before the session is closed? It looks I have to response quickly to continue, otherwise the session is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Alexa should play the reprompt speech. The reprompt is triggered after waiting 8s. The time to respond after the reprompt is 8s aswell. After this time frame the session closes.

To solve the problem with Alexa not triggering the reprompt you could try to send your response like this.

```
'AMAZON.YesIntent': function() {
    this.attributes["guessNumber"] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    this.handler.state = states.GUESSMODE;
    var speechOutput = 'Great! Try saying a number to start the game.';
    var repromptSpeech = 'Try saying a number.';
    this.emit(':ask', speechOutput, repromptSpeech);
};
```

Comment: How do you get the response from the reprompt speech?

Comment: it depends. either the response is a new intent. this means the response to the reprompt is triggering an intent. in this particular scenario i would recommend a slot, in which you store the the value you are askin in the speechOutput/repromptSpeech.